# Slow loading of winforms application

Tags: c#, windows, network-drive

I have a winform application that accesses a local database ( SQL CE ) and displays the data in a GUI. Now, when the application is launched from my hard drive, it is fast enough (about 2 seconds). However, my users need to run it from a shared/network drive. And in this case, the loading takes much longer, upto 12 or 13 seconds. Is there any work around for this, such as storing a copy of the database in the the local hardrive and then manipulating it and then storing it the network drive. Any other suggestions are welcome.

EDIT:
The thing is this form has to be used multiple times in a single run. And it takes 12 seconds to load on every load.

Comment: How are you loading the data into the form? Are you using DataGridView? Does the data change each time the form is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a [Splash screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen) or an "[In Progress](http://www.ajaxload.info/)" animated gif inorder to give the feeling that something is happening. I realize it won't make the data load faster, but in your case I think giving the user the feeling that something is happening in the background and that the application is not stuck, should be enough.

Comment: The thing is this form has to be used multiple times in a single run. And it takes 12 seconds to load on every load. The splash screen does not help.

Comment: @sunil shankar, will caching the data will work for you? Maybe we need more information about what is this data so we can understand the  nature of using it...

Answer (score 0):

Splash screen is a good idea to launch a slow windows form. We put initialize some of "caching job" ready to help your application run faster. 
About your idea:

> copy the database put it in the the local hardrive and then
>   manipulating it and then storing it the network drive

It is not partial good idea. It will take a lot of efforts if you working on multi-user environment. You will deal with concurrency, synchronize data between local database and network sharing database.
If you want to go with this idea, you should consider using Sync framework from MS. But so far, you should consider about splash screen.